# Border around button shows a bit of the background-color

Tags: css

I have a button that will show a grey border around it when it's getting hovered over. (I add `.hovered` when hovered over)

When I do this, the border still shows a bit of the background-color in the corners.

[image]

I'm not sure what the cause for this is.

My code:

```
            > span.button
            {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;

                @media (min-width: $screen-xs-min) and (max-width: $screen-sm-min - 1)
                {
                    bottom: 70px;
                }

                @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min)
                {
                    bottom:55px;
                }

                > a
                {
                    padding: 6px 25px 6px 25px;

                    background: rgba(196,18,21,1);
                    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(196,18,21,1) 0%, rgba(194,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(192,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 50%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 51%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 100%);
                    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(196,18,21,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(194,4,7,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(223,21,28,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(192,4,7,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(223,21,28,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(223,21,28,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(194,4,6,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(194,4,6,1)));
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(196,18,21,1) 0%, rgba(194,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(192,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 50%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 51%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 100%);
                    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(196,18,21,1) 0%, rgba(194,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(192,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 50%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 51%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 100%);
                    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(196,18,21,1) 0%, rgba(194,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(192,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 50%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 51%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 100%);
                    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(196,18,21,1) 0%, rgba(194,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(192,4,7,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 0%, rgba(223,21,28,1) 50%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 51%, rgba(194,4,6,1) 100%);
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c41215', endColorstr='#c20406', GradientType=0 );

                    border-radius: 10px;

                    color: #ffffff;
                }
            }
```

Hovered:

```
&.hovered > span.button a
{
    border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

Demo (without hover function, not important for this problem):

https://jsfiddle.net/zfmjL9gr/

Comment: Sure, I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be standard anti-aliasing due to pixel rounding as a result of the `border-radius`

Backgrounds extend to and are under the borders. You usually can't see them because the border color obscures it.

However, you can stop the background from being visible under the border by first adding a default **transparent** border (so the button doesn't change size) and applying `background-clip:padding-box` to the anchor.

[**Background-clip @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) and has excellent support.

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
}
a {
  padding: 6px 25px 6px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(196, 18, 21, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(196, 18, 21, 1) 0%, rgba(194, 4, 7, 1) 0%, rgba(223, 21, 28, 1) 0%, rgba(192, 4, 7, 1) 0%, rgba(223, 21, 28, 1) 0%, rgba(223, 21, 28, 1) 50%, rgba(194, 4, 6, 1) 51%, rgba(194, 4, 6, 1) 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* added */
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
span.button:hover a {
  border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<span class="button"><a href="#1">Button</a></span>
```

Comment: Thnx a lot! Works perfectly. Great explanation too!